# RaphaelJS: Can I use a fill operation inside a path? (w/o fill-attr)

Tags: vector, svg, path, raphael

I use `paper.path("M10 10L90 90")` function for drawing several (!) symbols (lines, triangles, ...). Means I only use one single path string. Now I want to fill only one of several symbols inside this single path. So I cannot use the `.attr("fill", "#123456")` function, as all symbols would be filled.

Does anyone knew a possibility to do the trick? (beside split the path into several paths)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using subpaths of your one big path:

```
Element.getSubpath(from, to);
```

Have a look at this example - http://jsfiddle.net/aStBR/